# How can you get the Elastic Beanstalk Application Version in your application?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We want to be able to retrieve the elastic beanstalk application version in our PHP code.  I don't see that EB passes it to us in any server configuration files, which I find it strange.  Does anyone else know how we might be able to get this?

Comment: AFAIK, when Elastic Beanstalk deploys your application to the cloud, it creates an archive with `git archive` command. The resulting archive file does not have any repository metadata.

Answer (score 7):

At least for Docker containers - you can use the information stored in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/manifest`.

Comment: Works for my stock flask image

Answer (score 4):

I've just been looking for a solution myself.

For now, at least, the following works:

```
unzip -z "${EB_CONFIG_SOURCE_BUNDLE}" | tail -n1
```

To elaborate,`$EB_CONFIG_SOURCE_BUNDLE` contains a path to the zip archive of your application (i.e. `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle`). The version tag is embedded as a comment in this file.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this, this apparently does not work for Ruby containers.

Comment: @mentat - does the envvar not exist or is the file missing, or both? It's expected that each lang environment has it's own deployment implementation but I would have thought the process of getting the code onto the server would be consistent.If you find a solution please could you follow up, or contribute to https://github.com/apancutt/aws-eb-newrelic-deploynotify

Comment: The envvar exists but it looks like the output is perhaps a hash. I'll take a closer look at the actual file to see where it's embedded. Are you using the aws git to push or something else?

Comment: Yes, using git to deploy (aws.push). The hash is the latest git commit which Elastic Beanstalk uses as the version label - at least for PHP applications.

Comment: I saw no such environment variable for a node container, so just used hardcoded `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle` (yuck)

Comment: `unzip -z "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle" | awk 'NR==2 { printf("%.7s\n", $1) }'` is the equivalant to `git rev-parse --short HEAD`

Answer (score 4):

Consolidating on the answers from @Georgij and @IanBlenke here are the ways you can find the version.

### 1. Most Reliable (Manifest)

You can `sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/manifest`

**Output:**

> {"RuntimeSources":{"PLATFORM_NAME":{"app-ae22-190115_152512":{"s3url":""}}},"DeploymentId":45,"Serial":53}

### 2. You can look at the eb-activity logs

Secondly you could look at the eb-activity logs. This will only show you in the log line... You have to assume it's been a successful installation too..

`tail /var/log/eb-activity.log | grep -i "app-.*@"`

[image]

Comment: Is the manifest file available during deployment? That seems like the best if so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AWS Elastic Beanstalk API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/Welcome.html) to retrieve your application version information.

[Describe Application Versions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeApplicationVersions.html) returns descriptions for existing application versions.

*Sample request*

```
https://elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazon.com/?ApplicationName=SampleApp
&Operation=DescribeApplicationVersions
&AuthParams
```

*Sample response*

```
<DescribeApplicationVersionsResponse xmlns="https://elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/docs/2010-12-01/">
  <DescribeApplicationVersionsResult>
    <ApplicationVersions>
      <member>
        <SourceBundle>
          <S3Bucket>amazonaws.com</S3Bucket>
          <S3Key>sample.war</S3Key>
        </SourceBundle>
        <VersionLabel>Version1</VersionLabel>
        <Description>description</Description>
        <ApplicationName>SampleApp</ApplicationName>
        <DateCreated>2010-11-17T03:21:59.161Z</DateCreated>
        <DateUpdated>2010-11-17T03:21:59.161Z</DateUpdated>
      </member>
    </ApplicationVersions>
  </DescribeApplicationVersionsResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>773cd80a-f26c-11df-8a78-9f77047e0d0c</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</DescribeApplicationVersionsResponse>
```

Answer (score 2):

While the best way is really to ask AWS directly:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments  | \
    jq -r '.Environments | .[] | .EnvironmentName + " " + .VersionLabel'
```

I've had limited success deducing the same 4 or 5 digit hash by using:

```
git rev-parse --short=4 $(git log -1 --pretty=format:%h)
```

Answer (score 2):

`tail /var/log/eb-activity.log | grep -i "\[Application update .*\] : Completed activity." | tail -1 | sed -E 's/.*Application update (.*)@.*/\1/'`

Outputs the actual app version ID like `app-2.15.0-31-gf4a2918` in our case.

This works from inside any EB EC2, requires no API hit or git repo (some deploy by zip). Useful for sending a notification about a recent deployment.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP application, you can get it using

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names <environment-name>`

You should add the below environment variables in the php script to get it working.

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

I have used `putenv()` function to set the environment variables and `shell_exec()` to get the json output. Parsed the json output to get the `VersionLabel` which is the actual application version.

Answer (score 0):

On the Python platform, the version details can be found in the EC2 instance:

```bash
sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_version_manifest.json
```