# Get version label of python app deployed to elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to know how I can get version label attribute of bundle deployed on elastic beanstalk to show it in my application.

As far as I know, bundles deployed with "git aws.push" are uploaded to an S3 bucket. My goal is to retrieve the version number and set it as environment variable or get it dinamically in order to be shown inside my django app.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find something for this?

Answer (score 1):

I see two potential ways. Although I must say I don't understand why this is not easier given this is a pretty legitimate use case, but it looks like it's not supported as of writing by AWS.

**Solution 1: generated version label**

Generate the version label on your side (for instance, with the commit hash), then make it part of your code.

For instance in your `Makefile`:

```
VERSION=$(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)

deploy: requirements.txt
    echo $(VERSION) > version.txt
    eb deploy --label $(VERSION)
.PHONY: deploy
```

Then you can just read this file from the instance. There are some other options, for instance using `sed` to put it as a variable in one of your file.

**Solution 2: get it from an undocumented file (unstable)**

I tried to find this metadata on the EC2 instance, and could find it in a file that is unfortunately owned by root:

```
[root@... ec2-user]# cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/manifest
{"RuntimeSources":{"yourappname":{"app-VERSION":{"s3url":""}}},"DeploymentId":24,"Serial":26}
[ec2-user@... ~]$ ls -la /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/manifest
-rw-rw---- 1 root awseb 98 Mar 22 17:57 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/manifest
```

I'm not sure if you could do this, but you could have a post deployment command that chown or copies this file in a place where you can read it. I might try that and let you know if it worked.

A similar question has been asked here: [How can you get the Elastic Beanstalk Application Version in your application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911123/how-can-you-get-the-elastic-beanstalk-application-version-in-your-application) (evidently I found it only after writing the above).